# How to get destination path when drag out a file from my application

Tags: c++builder

I complete a small demo to implement ole drag&drop.

My App looks like this:
[image]

when drag a item from TListView to system explorer can cause a copy.I use IDropSource,IDataObject and OLE

clipboard format CF_HDROP to implement,so I never need to kwon the destination path to copy to in my

code.

Is there any way to make me know the destination path?

I need a solution,thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no way to discover the destination, nor should you ever need to know it.  OLE drag&drop does not expose that information.  You provide the source data, the target decides what to do with it, and then tells you whether the result was a copy/move/link so you can cleanup the source data accordingly.

In this case, you are providing a filename as the source, and Explorer copies the file to the target folder for you.  Think of what would happen if you dropped the file into a virtual folder that has no filesystem path. The file can still be copied (even more so if you provide `CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR` and `CFSTR_FILECONTENT` in your source data). That is perfectly acceptable to OLE, and why the drag&drop is abstracted the way it is.

Comment: Thanks again for your help again:)It`s a hit or miss for me, so I will go on to implement my application.